# Error: Content of 'all' must match

Tags: xml, xsd

I am getting an error saying `The Content Of 'all' Must Match (annotation?, Element*). A Problem Was Found Starting At: Sequence.` while trying to validate my xml file using my XSD file. I have used `<xs:all>` because the number of `size` might change in the sub-root nodes. And I am not sure if the attribute tag should be added after or before the `<xs:all>` tag.

This is my xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Extra Large">
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

And this is my XSD file. Not sure if my  a has been placed in the right place though.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="catalog">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="product">
      <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="catalog_item">
         <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="item_number">
            <xs:simpleType>
             <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
             </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
           </xs:element>
           <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
           <xs:element name="size">
            <xs:complexType>
             <xs:all minOccurs="1">
              <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="color_swatch" type="xs:string">
                <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                 </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="image" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
             </xs:all>
            </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="gender" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
 <attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
     <attribute name="product_image" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to allow several  `<size>` elements in a `<catalog_item>`, you need to set `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on the `size` element.

```
<xs:element name="size" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

Afterwards, you'll need to correct the content definition of `<size>` - there's no point using `<xs:all>` here (remember that `<xs:all>` means "*theses elements need to occur exactly once in this context, whatever the order*"). This should meet your requirements:

```
    <xs:element name="size" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="color_swatch" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                  <xs:attribute name="image" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

PS: you forgot the "`xs:`" prefix on the last two attribute declarations:

```
 <attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
 <attribute name="product_image" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: That solved the current issue. But now I am getting an error "saying Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element 'catalog_item'. No Child Element Is Expected At This Point., Line '15', Column '38'"
I think this error came up in the xml file. Is it because the 'color_swatch' element defined in my xsd file not allowing the xml to have more than one element?

Comment: Most probably you need to set `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on `<xs:element name="catalog_item">` as well.